# 'Connection aborted.'when using requests

Tags: python, python-requests, scraper

```
import requests
url = 'http://femhzs.mofcom.gov.cn/fecpmvc/pages/fem/CorpJWList_nav.pageNoLink.html;jsessionid=8C736597A2750E8A4D32363D15A9A5DF?session=T&sp=1&sp=S+_t1.CORP_CDE%2C+_t1.id&sp=T&sp=S'
headers = { 'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36"}
r = requests.get(url,headers = headers)
```

My code is shown above, while this get an connection aborted error. What should I do, need some help.

Comment: please post the stack trace text

Answer (score 0):

Your URL doesn't work but you're using everything in the correct way

```
In [168]: url = 'https://www.google.com'

In [169]: response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

In [170]: response.status_code
Out[170]: 200
```

Comment: url = 'http://femhzs.mofcom.gov.cn/fecpmvc/pages/fem/CorpJWList_nav.pageNoLink.html;jsessionid=8C736597A2750E8A4D32363D15A9A5DF?session=T&sp=1&sp=S+_t1.CORP_CDE%2C+_t1.id&sp=T&sp=S'     this url has no probelm, I can access to it in Chrome,while when I use requests, it is aborted.

Comment: I am so sorry for this. While I still want to ask are there any other ways to try to solve it?

Comment: looks like it might be a problem with the server you're trying to connect to https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/4413